# BizTalk 2006 and consuming RESTful Web services

Tags: rest, web, service, biztalk

I need to consume RESTful Web services in my orchestration in BizTalk 2006 (.NET 2.0). Can anyone post some tutorials or related web site links. I know many places but those are for BizTalk 2009/20010 and later version and above .Net 2.0. But I need to implement it in BizTalk 2006 .Net 2.0

Comment: Can't you just try to follow the 2009/2010 tutorials and when you get stuck or something is different, search for / ask about that specific thing you are stuck with?

Comment: Thanks MDeSchaepmeester for your quick response. Yes, I am trying. Now for example, I get problem with "Error The type or namespace name 'IEndpointBehavior' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)". I have the reference to "System.ServiceModel...". Also other error related to "BehaviorExtensionElement", "IClientMessageInspector". I am using following tutorials:   http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/2474.invoke-restful-web-services-with-biztalk-server-2010.aspx#ReST_MessageInspector

Comment: Unfortunately, these interfaces are .NET 3.0 or higher. There are a number of workarounds here. First of all; see if you can set the target .NET framework of your project to 3.0 or higher (you need to install the newer version of course). If that does not work, search if someone has adapted those interfaces to be .NET 2.0 compliant somewhere, or usage of them in Biztalk 2006. (I can't find anything though). Last option is to ditch the need for them and emulate their behaviour through other ways. If all of the above fails - either upgrade your BTS (recommended anyway) or ...

Comment: ... You can build another web service that consumes the RESTful one and exposes an API that is more easily consumed by BTS 2006. Effectively you build the adapter between Biztalk and the RESTful web service.

Answer (score 2):

A number of options here, based on the trouble you're experiencing when following the [MSDN tutorial](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/2474.invoke-restful-web-services-with-biztalk-server-2010.aspx) for the 2010 version, in order of relative ease:

### Set the target framework to .NET 3.0/3.5

For the DLL that contains the C# stuff of your project, this should not be a problem. Whether the rest of your solution will work (BizTalk stuff), or whether the BizTalk engine/adapter will interface with this DLL - absolutely no idea.

**Easiest/quickest solution that has a chance to not work at all or break later.**

### Upgrade your BizTalk server version

Your BTS is 8 years old. I wouldn't justify its use in a live production environment where new requirements show up (exactly what brought you here).

**This solution is the most valuable but might not be easy to execute and might be time-consuming**.

### Build a Facade

Basically you can create a seperate webservice to bring the existing one and BizTalk 2006 closer together. The new web service, not depending on old frameworks, can consume the RESTful web service easily. It should expose an API that is moulded to circumvene the technical impediments of the old BTS version so it can be consumed more easily by the standard adapters out-of-the box (SOAP comes to mind).

**The most elegant solution to the atomic problem - moderately time consuming, guaranteed to work. Does not address any "bigger" issues however (outdated platform).**

Comment: Thanks again. Yes, I know my BTS is too old. However, my client does not want to upgrade/update to newer version. I have no idea why. I have many other challenges to keep the old BTS running in modern era. Any way, I also was thinking creating a proxy WCF to invoke the REST that you have suggested. That seems my only option. Many thanks once again for your kind solution and time.

Comment: @KoeKayttaja How is your relation to the client on a business level? Are you purely a technical guy or do you also discuss higher-level stuff with them? If so, try to find out the reasons and convince them to upgrade anyway. If not, discuss this with your superiors who _do_ comunicate with the client on a higher level. If it's licencing reasons you're out of luck, but if they aren't sure about the investment - tell them that problems like these will pop up more frequently and the development cost will gradually increase all the time.